# Fixing a Wi-Fi hotspot in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I've run into a number of issues related to wireless networking(under Ubuntu 14.04). Is it possible to fix a set of hotspots so that the connection won't be dropped regardless of the number of available hotspots?

For example, if there are three hotspots: A, B and C and I only have credentials for B how may I choose it as a permanent option meaning that no connection attempt should be made towards A and C regardless of their signal strength?

Comment: If you have tried to connect to A and C before, network profiles for A and C may have been created. If so, go to Network Manager (WiFi icon on top left) > Edit connections > Select A > delete. Repeat for C. Then check the box in B to automatically connect when available as explained below.

Comment: @ user68186 I have already done that. The profiles are automatically created when the hotspots are detected.

Comment: If you delete the profiles they should not be created again unless you try to connect to them.

Comment: Right now my laptop is detecting 9 other hotspots (+1 it is connected to). It didn't create any profiles for these 9 hotspots in the Network Manager.

Answer (score 3):

Edit connection --> click on B --> edit --> general --> tick Automatically connect to this network when it is available. This should be ticked only for connection B.

[image]